# Comparar duas colunas no excel e criar a terceira

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-sheets

Preciso comparar o item da Coluna A com todos os itens da coluna B, se este item não estiver presente na coluna B, ele é gerado na coluna C. Qual fórmula eu preciso usar para fazer isso?

[image: Exemplo no excel]

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver sozinho, usei a seguinte função

```
=FILTER(A2:A; NOT(COUNTIF(B2:B; A2:A)))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]